# Cannot read XML comments using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I cannot retrieve the XML node comments. Is there a different way to retrieve it? .Value did not work either. I could not find anything here in StackOverflow.
This is what I am doing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components>
    <component name="AAA">
        <sample>
            <!-- blah blah blah --> 
        </sample>
        <data>
            <!-- blah blah blah -->             
        </data>
    </component>

    <component name="BBB">
        <sample>
            <!-- blah blah blah --> 
        </sample>
        <data>
            <!-- blah blah blah -->             
        </data>     
    </component>    
</components>

public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sample { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);

    Component components = doc.Descendants("component")
        .Select(x => new Component
        {
            Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
            Sample = (string)x.Element("sample"), //cannot read value
            Data = (string)x.Element("data") //cannot read value
        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: comments are not elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675167.aspx
So the code ended up looking like this:

```
    var components = doc
        .Descendants("component")
        .Select(x => new Component()
        {
            Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
            Sample = x.Element("sample").Nodes().OfType<XComment>()
                                                                .Select(s=>s.Value)
                                                                .Aggregate(
                                                                    new StringBuilder(), 
                                                                    (s,i)=>s.Append(i),
                                                                    s => s.ToString()
                                                                ),
            Data = x.Element("data").Nodes().OfType<XComment>()
                                                                .Select(s=>s.Value)
                                                                .Aggregate(
                                                                    new StringBuilder(), 
                                                                    (s,i)=>s.Append(i),
                                                                    s => s.ToString()
                                                                )
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var components =
    doc
        .Descendants("component")
        .Select(x => new Component()
        {
            Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
            Sample = String.Join("", x.Element("sample").Nodes().OfType<XComment>()),
            Data = String.Join("", x.Element("data").Nodes().OfType<XComment>()),
        });
```

Comment: Now I am getting: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XComment>' to 'string[]'

Comment: You may not have a reference you need or you're using an earlier framework - it worked for me as it is.

Comment: yep that worked in .Net4.0 but not 3.5. We cannot use 4.0 at this time..sighss I know right.

Comment: @Max - Did you try putting a `.ToArray()` after each of the `OfType` calls?